# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+x+1}dx $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to calculate integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+x+1}dx $$

It's rather easy to find when the limits of integration are $[-\infty, \infty],$
but with lower limit being zero?

Is it at all computable with some basic knowledge of complex analysis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps letting $x\mapsto1/x$ will help...

Comment: Due to the lack of parity of the integrand function the final outcome involves sine and cosine integrals. A fast way to check that is to consider tha Laplace transform of $\cos(x)$ and the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$.

Comment: Have you tried $\frac{\cos (z)\log (z)}{1+z+z^2}$ with key-hole contour around the branch cut of logarithm along positive real axis?

Comment: @r9m: there is still no way to avoid a sine/cosine integral in the end.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes .. OP was looking for complex analysis :) The integral along the arc should reduce to sine/cosine integrals.

Comment: @r9m: oh, sure, that is correct.

Comment: @r9m could you please post an answer with this calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As Robert Israel answered.*

Consider the general problem of $$I=\int \frac {\cos(x)}{(x-a)(x-b)} \,dx$$ and use partial fraction decomposition $$\frac {1}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac 1{x-a} -\frac 1{x-b}\right)$$ So, basically we are left with  integrals
$$J= \int \frac {\cos(x)}{x-c} \,dx=\int \frac {\cos(y+c)}{y} \,dy=\cos (c)\int\frac{ \cos (y)}{y}\,dy-\sin (c)\int\frac{ \sin (y)}{y}\,dy$$that is to say $$J=\cos (c)\, \text{Ci}(y)-\sin (c)\,\text{Si}(y)$$ where appear the sine and cosine integrals. For $y$, the bounds are now $c$ and $\infty$ making $$K=\int_c^\infty \frac {\cos(y+c)}{y} \,dy=\text{Si}(c)\, \sin (c)-\text{Ci}(c) \,\cos (c)-\frac{\pi }{2}  \sin (c)$$ Now, it is sure that with $a=-\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2} $ and $b=-\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, we shall arrive to quite ugly complex expressions for the posted integral.

Its decimal representation is $I\approx 0.451312142585023$ for which $RIES$ proposes things like $\frac{4}{5 \sqrt{\pi }}$ and $\log \left(\frac{1}{3} 2^{2 \phi -1}\right)$; however, $ISC$ did not find anything like this number.

Answer (score 5):

By [a useful property of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) we have

$$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x+x^2}\,dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}s\right)se^{-s/2}}{1+s^2}\,ds \tag{1}$$
with
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha s}}{1\pm i s}\,ds = \frac{1}{2}e^{\mp i\alpha}\left(\pi\pm 2i\text{Ci}(\alpha)-2\text{Si}(\alpha)\right)\tag{2}$$
for any $\alpha:\text{Re}(\alpha)>0$. So the original integral depends on [sine and cosine integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).
Its numerical evaluation is not that hard, however: it is enough to apply a few steps of integration by parts, then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, to the RHS of $(1)$. This leads to $I\approx\frac{\pi}{7}$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fractions and the Ei function.  It can be converted to incomplete Gamma functions, but
 I don't think the answer can be expressed using only elementary functions.